# Django NoReverseMatch at /pet/

Tags: django

I'm working on simple a pet store app

I encountered this error a couple of times and I managed to understand it and fix it but in this situation . I don't know what went wrong . Everything seem clear to me .

It says I have an error in my store.html at the location of the {% url world:brazil animal.id %} but I have define the namespace already.

```
  Reverse for 'brazil' with arguments '('',)' and keyword arguments '{}' not found.
  Error during template rendering

  In template C:\djcode\mysite\pet\templates\store.html, error at line 5
  Reverse for 'brazil' with arguments '('',)' and keyword arguments '{}' not found.
  1     Sydney's Pet Store
  2     {% if store %}
  3     <ul>
  4     {% for a in store %}
  5     <li><a href ="{% url world:brazil animal.id %}">{{ a.name }}</li>
  6     {% endfor %}
  7     
  8     </ul>
  9     {% endif %}
```

My store.html

```
Sydney's Pet Store
{% if store %}
<ul>
        {% for a in store %}
    <li><a href ="{% url world:brazil animal.id %}">{{ a.name }}</li>
    {% endfor %}

</ul>
{% endif %}
```

My views.py

```
 from pet.models import Store , Pet
 from django.shortcuts import render_to_response ,get_object_or_404

 def index(request):
     store = Store.objects.all()
     return render_to_response ('store.html',{'store':store})

 def brazil(request , animal_id):
     store = get_object_or_404(Store , Pet, pk=animal_id)
     return render_to_response ('animal.html',{'store':store})
```

My pet app URLCONF:

```
 from django.conf.urls import patterns,include , url 

 urlpatterns = patterns ('pet.views',
     url(r'^$','index',name = 'index'),
     url(r'^(?P<poll_id>\d+)/$','brazil',name ='brazil'),

     )
```

my main URCONF:

```
  from django.conf.urls import patterns, include, url
   from django.contrib import admin
  from django.conf import settings
  from django.contrib.staticfiles.urls import staticfiles_urlpatterns
  from django.conf.urls.static import static

  admin.autodiscover()
  urlpatterns = patterns('',

      url(r'^pet/',include('pet.urls' , namespace='world' )),

  ) + static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)

  urlpatterns += staticfiles_urlpatterns()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because you didn't define animal.id. What you have render in your view is only store variable.

```
Sydney's Pet Store
{% if store %}
<ul>
        {% for a in store %}
    <li><a href ="{% url world:brazil a.id %}">{{ a.name }}</li>
    {% endfor %}

</ul>
{% endif %}
```